# update two parameter in url

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is working if parameter which is passed is only one.

But When I pass two parameters, the `className` parameter is not updated on the second changed, it added new `className` parameter.

This is where the change function goes.

```
$('#classRoom').change(function(){
    var name = 'room_id';
    var value = $('#majorRoom').val();
    var className = 'room_type_id';
    var classValue = $('#classRoom').val();
    addOrUpdateUrlParam(name, value, className, classValue)
})
```

And this is the function to update the params.

```
function addOrUpdateUrlParam(name, value, className, classValue)
    {
        var href = window.location.href;
        var regex = new RegExp("[&\\?]" + name + "=");
        var regex2 = new RegExp("[&\\?]" + className + "=");
        if(regex.test(href))
            {
                regex = new RegExp("([&\\?])" + name + "=\\d+");
                regex2 = new RegExp("([&\\?])" + className + "=\\d+");
                window.location.href = href.replace(regex, "$1" + name + "=" + value) + (regex2, "&" + className + "=" + classValue);
            }
        else
            {
                if(href.indexOf("?") > -1)
                  window.location.href = href + "&" + name + "=" + value + "&" + className + "=" + classValue;
                else
                  window.location.href = href + "?" + name + "=" + value + "&" + className + "=" + classValue;
            }
    }
```

Can anybody help, please.

Many thanks in advance!

The first change:

```
  'myweb.com/index.php?blabla=3&room_id=13&room_type_id=1835`
```

The second change:

```
  'myweb.com/index.php?blabla=3&room_id=13&room_type_id=1835$1room_type_id=1832`
```

Comment: Instead of the distracting complexity of your various regex code could you just show us the final url that does work and the final url that doesn't work.

Comment: Please see my last update

Comment: did you want a $ symbol in your last url. Presumably you wanted that to be an &.

Comment: No,what I want is only &

Comment: Then I recommend getting rid of you regex logic and simply construct your urls with string concatenation.

Comment: Can you show me it as an answer?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do with this line:                 window.location.href = href.replace(regex, "$1" + name + "=" + value) + (regex2, "&" + className + "=" + classValue); Why are you adding the string "$1" to the value name? That is the code that results in $1room_type_id

Answer (score 0):

I think the "g" modifier is missing when calling RegExp()
For example, instead of:

`regex = new RegExp("([&\\?])" + name + "=\\d+");`

It should be:

`regex = new RegExp("([&\\?])" + name + "=\\d+", "g");`

By default, only first ocurrence is affected. With "g" modifier you tell RegExp to apply globally to all matches.